# .htaccess produces 404 on server, but passes htaccess validators

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I'm stumped as to why this isn't working. When I use an online `.htaccess` validator all appears fine. It works as expected. However, that same `.htaccess` on the production server nets a 404 response.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api/index.php?_REQUEST=$1 [NC,L]
```

In `000-default.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

For some context. The site uses a subdomain. It's running on an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Apache2 2.4.41, and PHP 7.4.3

This exact same configuration works just fine on another instance, the only difference being the subdomain. The desired result:

`subdomain.example/api/data/data` rewrites to `subdomain.example/api/index.php?Querystring`

Sending data/data as a querystring. While I am no `.htaccess` expert, far from it, I am stumped as to why this isn't working and producing a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution:
Make sure you haven't left the same .htaccess file in the actual directory you are trying to rewrite. In this case, api/. Removing the errant .htaccess file and rebooting apache resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The effect of simply enabling the rewrite engine (ie. `RewriteEngine On`) in the subdirectory is that the parent mod_rewrite directives are completely overridden. And `^api/(.*)$` won't match when used in `/api/.htaccess`.